# Unable to Find out Foreign Key related values without duplication

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to get all the  Images and bullet_points of a single product. Images and Bullet_Points have foreign key Product_ID for reference. However I get a total of 40 rows as a result even when i only have 8 bullet_points ,5 images for a single product.what is it that i am doing wrong?

[image]

Below is my linq query that i am performing .

```
from p in Products
from i in Images
from s in Specifications
where p.ProductID==i.Product_ID && p.ProductID==5002
where p.ProductID==s.Product_ID && p.ProductID==5002
select new  { p.ProductID,i.Image_URL,s.Bullet_Point}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You want to receive both `Images` and `Specifications` in a single query. This leads to relational multiplication so the number of records becomes `8 * 5 = 40`. Try to make 2 separate queries, one for `Images` and another for `Specifications`.

Comment: Maybe you want to get only one records of `Product` with two related collections of `Images` and `Specifications`?

Comment: Yes, you are right.. A single product has multiple images and multiplel bullet_points  binded with a foreign key.Can i retrieve all of them in a single query without duplication.@IvanGritsenko or Should i change the architecture?

Comment: @Arun3x3 The architecture is fine as well as your query. You just cannot get what you want in a single request. A table only got 2 dimensions, so your query result exactly in what Ivan Gritsenko explains. If you delete duplicated entries you will loose image information. So in fact there are no duplicated rows. So two queries are the best solution here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Sebi .I can arrange it in two queries but the problem is in the context of model to view . How can i send two queries as a one view object to a view because i want to pass the information so that it can be displayed and edited .

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
from p in Products
join i in Images on i.Product_ID equals p.ProductID into imgs
join s in Specifications on s.Product_ID equals p.ProductID into specs
where p.ProductID == 5002
select new { p.ProductID, 
    urls = imgs.Select(x => x.Image_URL), 
    bulletPoints = specs.Select(x => x.Bullet_Point) };
```

Why not to use navigation properties from `Product`? I can see your `Product` model has `Images` and `Specifications` properties. So you may also try:

```
Products.Where(p => p.ProductID == 5002).Select(p => new { 
    p.ProductID, 
    urls = p.Images.Select(x => x.Image_URL), 
    bulletPoints = p.Specifications.Select(x => x.Bullet_Point) })
```